# Office Addins file in its TypeScript version doesn't work

Tags: typescript, office-js

I'm using a template found in https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-In-TS-Start

Basically, it is the default Excel Office Addins template that Visual Studio generates, but modified to also support TypeScript.

The file `Home.ts` in the root is already in its TypeScript version.

There is also a file called `FunctionFile.js` (inside `Functions` folder), and I wanted to write my own functions there, but in TypeScript.
So, I created a ribbon control of `ExecuteFunction` type pointing to a function called `myTest`.

Inside `FunctionFile.js`, I wrote the code below, and it worked as expected when I clicked in the addin command:

```
(function () {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    };
})();

function myTest() {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange("A1").values = [["I was clicked!"]];

        return ctx.sync();
    }).catch(errorHandler);
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

So far, so good. But, as I mentioned, I want everything to work in TypeScript, so I tried renaming it to `FunctionFile.ts` and replaced the code by its TypeScript version:

```
(() => {
    Office.initialize = () => {
    }
})();

function myTest(): void {
    Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
        ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange("A1").values = [["I as clicked!"]];

        await ctx.sync();
    }).catch(errorHandler);
}

function errorHandler(error): void {
    console.log(error);
}
```

When I tried to run, the function `myTest` is called, but I got this error when it reaches (I think) `Excel.run` method:

```
HTML1300: Ocorreu navegação.
FunctionFile.html
ReferenceError: 'Promise' is not defined (I translated this)
{
[functions]: ,
__proto__: { },
description: "'Promise' não está definido",
message: "'Promise' não está definido",
name: "ReferenceError",
number: -2146823279,
stack: "ReferenceError: 'Promise' não está definido
at Anonymous function (https://localhost:44356/Functions/FunctionFile.js:2:5)
at Anonymous function (https://localhost:44356/Functions/FunctionFile.js:42:32)
at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:205600)
at yi (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:236067)
at st (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:236154)
at d (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:235974)
at c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:234560)"
}
```

Actually, the error happens in the JavaScript layer below (that it is too messed up to analyze):

```
return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(result.value); }).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
})
```

Why when I convert `Home.js` to `Home.ts` it works, but the same doesn't happen with `FunctionFile.js` to `FunctionFile.ts`? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `async/await` keywords, TypeScript expects you to provide a Promise implementation.

From the book "Building Office Add-ins using Office.js" (https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/) [Disclaimer, I am the author of said book]:

[image: Promises discussion]

In your case (and something that I'll add a clarification for in the book), the `async` keyword is effectively creating a Promise for you, so the guidance above still applies.  In [Script Lab](https://aka.ms/scriptlab), we include the library core-js by default (option #3), which provides a Promise polyfill:

[image: Script Lab]

If you prefer not to bring in an extra library, you can also rely on the fact that Office.js (as long as you're using ExcelApi 1.2+ or WordApi 1.2+) includes a Promise library.  So all you need to do, if you want, is add the following one-liner inside of `Office.initialized = function() { ... }`, which will polyfill the global `window.Promise` with the Office.js-provided-one:

```
window.Promise = OfficeExtension.Promise;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I could make it work by adding a reference to `core-js` in `FunctonFile.html` head. The other method - by adding `window.Promise = OfficeExtension.Promise;` in `FunctionFile.ts`'s initialization didn't work (I got the compilation error "Property 'Promise' does not exist on type 'Window'").

Comment: For the other method, did you put it inside of "office.initialized"?  It needs to be inside of "office.initialized",  even if the rest of your click handlers are not.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my previous comment. To make the compiler happy, do `(window as any).Promise = OfficeExtension.Promise`

Comment: Yes! It worked with `(window as any)`. Thank you, Michael!