# How to Polyfill Promise in Visual Studio 2017 Office Add-in TypeScript Project

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, es6-promise, office-js, polyfills

I am using TypeScript in an Office Add-in, and I want to use async / await functions specifically.  The project fails to compile with "TS2468 TypeScript Cannot find global value 'Promise'."

I have read on here that I have to create a polyfill for Promise, but so far have not been able to figure out how to get a polyfill working in Visual Studio 2017.  I am attempting to use core-js, and have installed it in to the project using npm install core-js.  I can see core-js is installed under node_modules. npm also created a package.json file with the following:

`{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.5.3"
  }
}`

Here is my tsconfig.json file:
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}`

I have `require('core-js');` declared at the top of FunctionFile.ts, but the error persists.

I followed the guidance provided in this question :
[Office Addins file in its TypeScript version doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461312/office-addins-file-in-its-typescript-version-doesnt-work)

Using the same add-in I created based on this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/convert-javascript-to-typescript

I added the following to my test TypeScript file:

```
(function () {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        (window as any).Promise = OfficeExtension.Promise;
    };
})();

async function test() {
    return 'hello';
}
```

I still get the same error when building the project. "TS2468 TypeScript Cannot find global value 'Promise'."  I also tried it with `(window as any).Promise = OfficeExtension.Promise;` at the top.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461312/office-addins-file-in-its-typescript-version-doesnt-work/44461611#44461611

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office Addins file in its TypeScript version doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461312/office-addins-file-in-its-typescript-version-doesnt-work)

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft, Using the same add-in I created based on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/convert-javascript-to-typescript, I added the following to my test TypeScript file: `(function () {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        (window as any).Promise = OfficeExtension.Promise;
        // If you need to initialize something you can do so here.
    };
})();

async function test() {
    return 'hello';
}`  I still get the same error when building the project. "TS2468 TypeScript Cannot find global value 'Promise'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this can be resolved by adding the following `lib` property to the `compilerOptions` object your **tsconfig.json** file:

```
"lib": [ "es5", "dom", "es2015.promise" ]
```

In other words, update the contents of your **ts.config** file to look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [ "es5", "dom", "es2015.promise" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @J Allen -- thanks for raising this issue. We've updated the docs to include guidance about including the `lib` property in **ts.config**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/convert-javascript-to-typescript.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks again Kim!

Comment: Happy to help.  Also, a shout-out to @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft for talking through this with me...thanks, Michael!

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft -- FYI, adding that to the tsconfig file did fix the issue for the compiler, but it was then failing at run time.  I fixed that by adding `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>` to the FunctionFile.html page.  Not sure if that is the absolutely best way to do it but its working for me now.